# Multiple template urls Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building a front-end in Angular 6, and I will need a couple of components that need to have different html structures based on who is logged in.

This can vary from 2 to 20+ different templates, so I would really like to be able
to have those in different files, and point the templateUrl to the correct file instead of using *ngIf to decide what part of a template should render.

Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHtml` attributes in template and you can give template dynamically

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
            <div [innerHtml]="myTemplate">
            </div>
          `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private myTemplate: any = '';
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {

 // write condition here

    http.get('/template-path', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => this.myTemplate = data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't this break the angular variables in the html? That is {{ myVariable }}

Comment: did you try out this? You have to puts all your variables in component

Comment: I just tested this, and angular variables don't work, and neither does the styling